# How to embed html code in php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
 <div class="home-description"> 
 <?php the_content() .
 echo "<a class='read-more' href=".
 echo get_bloginfo('url').
     echo "/about-us>".
 echo "more</a>"
 ?>
 </div>
```

It's not working!!! Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo<<<_HTML
<a class='read-more' href="somepage.html">More</a>
_HTML;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this

```
 <div class="home-description"> 
 <?php echo the_content() .
 '<a class"mread-more" href="'. 
 get_bloginfo('url') .
      '/about-us">more</a>';
 ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:

```
<div class="home-description"> 
 <?php the_content() ?>
 <a class='read-more' href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url');?>/about-us>">more</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more...</a>
```